# CSV with 56.6mb of data, store as CSV file or in database?

Tags: php, csv, phpmyadmin, large-files

I am creating a website where I want people to submit location addresses. To avoid spelling mistakes I would like users to select from  a list (town name, county).

I came across the following site http://www.doogal.co.uk/london_postcodes.php which allows me to download a 56 mb large csv file containing the location data I need.

However I have never used a csv file larger than 1mb before with more than 30000 rows of data on my websites. Usually I would just upload to PhpMyAdmin.

What is better? Uploading the csv file to PHPmyadmin database or accessing the '.csv' file directly using php?

Regards

Comment: 'Better' is subjective, but i expect the database will be more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. I am not so sure that using a CSV is benefitial since using a database will allow you to

1. Cache data
2. Create Indexes for fast searching
3. Create complex queries
4. Do data manipulation, etc

The only way I would think a CSV is better, is if you would use always, all the data. Otherwise, I would go for a database. The end result would be much more organized, much faster, and you could build on top of it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do lookups, I'd recommend you put it into a database table and add indexes on the fields that you will be searching on (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). A flat file is not a good way to store data that you have to access or filter quickly.